# When I dockerize a sinatra app, what happens to the app's log files?

Tags: logging, docker, sinatra

Does it even make sense to ask this question, seeing how the container
is an ephemeral object? If the app's logs aren't being redirected to a 
persistent service (and they aren't), are they not even saved on the
container's (ephemeral) file system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the Docker container is not necessarily an ephemeral object. If you do a:

```
docker stop <container-id>
```

The files remain in your `/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/<container-id>` directory (or whatever your Docker home dir is.

You can run:

```
docker start <container-id>
```

to restart the container and the same container will come up.  For you to remove the container you would have to do a:

```
docker rm <container-id>
```

Now going back to the question of your log file, it depends where you are logging to. Are you logging to a file ? stdout ? If you are logging to a file then file should be under `/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/<container-id>` or `/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/<container-id>/var/log/app.log` or wherever you put your log file.

Comment: Something's going on with the sinatra app I've been using for testing. If I substitute in any other app, be it rails, perl, even bash, stdout logging works fine. So closing this.

Comment: So, are there any best practices how to handle logging output from services in docker containers? I feel like everyone and their mother has their own solution :-/

Comment: @Manuel I answered that a little bit here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076878/logging-solution-for-multiple-containers-running-on-same-host/32079823#32079823 also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083256/docker-for-rails-app/32085389#32085389